# Deploy JBOSS FUSE 6 as service on application server

Tags: jboss, esb, application-server, jbossfuse

I want to deploy JBoss FUSE as war or in any other way on application server (Tomcat for example). In documentation for the old version (3.5) of FUSE there was described a simple way for doing that by running special maven project from examples folder.

But for later releases I just can't find any information about possibility of doing that. I thought that deploying ESB as a service on application server is standard way of working with it, but I only found tutorials for installing FUSE as standalone instance or system service.

I would like to know how can I deploy it or why I can't do this if thats the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer supported. JBoss Fuse 6.x is a standalone application that has its own container (based on Apache Karaf).
The current 6.x release requires running on top of Apache Karaf.

> Though we have plans to make Fuse (that would be Fuse Fabric) container agnostic so you in the
>   future would be able to run Fuse on JBoss AS, Tomcat, Karaf, Standalone, in the cloud, etc. Though we focus on JBoss AS, Tomcat, and Karaf as the main containers at first we aim to support.